# Centos 6.3 iptables with Windows external network drive

Tags: linux, centos, iptables

I currently have a mounted windows external network drive so that I can run bash scripts that save to this mounted file.  It works fine when iptables is turned off, but when I turn iptables on I receive the error "cannot access /mnt/external-folder: Host is down"

I have tried several different iptables rules, but I have been unsuccessful.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the result of mount:

```
192.168.100.108:/Powerhouse/Public/Programming on /mnt/Programming type cifs (rw)
```

Here is my iptables config so far.  I removed all my attempts to get the mnt to the external folder working:

```
:INPUT DROP [5:923]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
:LOGGING - [0:0]
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2369 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.100.0/24 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 2369 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 3306 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 192.168.100.108/32 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of `mount` into your question, making it clear which is the external drive?

Comment: info about iptables rules in your firewall will be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to allow samba ports for cifs to work:

```
-I INPUT -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport 139
-I INPUT -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport 445
-I INPUT -j ACCEPT -p udp --dport 137:138
```